# Calculate how much of a fixed discount goes between two total

Tags: javascript

I'm having a very difficult time trying to figure out how to split a discount between two totals. Example i have a fixed discount of 100 and two totals one is 5000 the other is 468. So of that 100 like 95% is given to the 5000 and the other 5% is given to the 468. Any direction would help thank you and this is my code thus far.

```
subtotalDiscount = discount / 100 * subTotal;
nonTaxableTotalDiscount = discount / 100 * nonTaxableTotal;
```

Comment: what is the value of `subTotal` and `nonTaxableTotal`?

Comment: it is a dynamic value so they can be any amount

Comment: i mean, is it 0.95 or 95?

Comment: Those percentages i gave are just examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1) 100/(5000+468) * 5000
2) 100/(5000+468) * 468
```

Comment: Thank you this is correct and what i need but how would i correct the rounding issue so that both added totals returns 100 instead of 99.999999999999 i get 91.44111192392099 on the 5000 and 8.558888076079005 on 468

Comment: 1) a = 100/(5000+468) * 5000
2) b = 100 - a

Comment: Thank you sr for your help i was literally banging my head against the wall. I went and just did a Math.round() on the individual values to fix the rounding issue.

Comment: @Darkrum, JavaScript is jacked with floating point numbers (as are most languages).

Comment: I don't think Math.round() solves the issue properly. What if 2 values have fractional part .5 ? It's better to subtract the value from the total to get the second value.

Comment: But how would you go about this would you go off how which amount is higher? or does it not matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter :) Just use subtraction for the last value.

Comment: Okay good just checking that there's no possibility for it to return a negative value

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is just a way to make these values calculate automatically based on some fixed discount. Here is something you could base it on:

```
largeSub = 5000;
smallSub = 468;
fixedDiscount = 100;
largeDiscountPercent = .95;
smallDiscountPercent = .05;
largeTotal = largeSub - fixedDiscount * largeDiscountPercent;
smallTotal = smallSub - fixedDiscount * smallDiscountPercent;
```

Comment: no i need it to calculate how much of the portion of the discount is given to each total

Comment: the percent is not a fixed amount